# Is there any gdk which is based on SDK 4.0.4?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, gdk

For some reason I will develop a app in Google glass which is based on sdk 4.0.4(API 15).
I know gdk is delivered with sdk 4.4.2(API 19), so i can't use it.
Is there any gdk which is based on sdk 4.0.4 now?

PS: I can't update system for Google glass because this glass is not belong to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only build using SDK 4.4.2 and newer for glasswear. Refer to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start).

Answer (score 0):

There simply is no GDK based on SDK 4.0.4. Google Glass's base SDK is 4.4.2